# I have a file that is encoded in RIFF. How can I send this file through an ajax post response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, ascii, riff

I am trying to preserve the RIFF encoding of the file while sending it back as a response, as shown below.

```
router.post('/someroute', function(req,res,next){

  var riff1= fs.readFileSync(somefilepath);            
  res.send(riff1);
}
```

When I receive a response from my AJAX call, and examine the response it is in an ASCII format. I have tried to change the encoding of readFileSync to utf8, but that isn't working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Blob();

```
var riff1 = fs.readFileSync(somefilepath);            
var blob = new Blob([riff1], {type: 'audio/mpeg'});
res.send(blob);
```

Should work.